# Properly casting a member variable for a 2D array

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, casting

I am getting compiling errors because I cannot properly specify a class member variable as a pointer to a 2D array.  This board has many examples of receiving pointers to 2D arrays, but in each case the pointer is used immediately to access the data in the array which is not what I'm doing.  I want to save the pointer to the 2D array for general use in the class.  I can't determine the correct cast.

No matter what I try, I get an error like this.
  error C2440: 'type cast' : cannot convert from ...  to ...

Additionally I'm not able to assign the member variable to NULL.

I am using MS VC++ 2008 Express.

Here's my code, simplified:

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
  int _2D[2][3] = { {1,2,3}, {11,22,33} };

  return 0;
}

class C
{
 public:
    C(int* _2dIn[3]) {                  // <- I don't know how to cast this properly.
        init();
    m_p2d = (int *[3])_2dIn;    // <-  The casting error always points to this line.
    }
    ~C(void);

    void init(void) {
        m_p2d = NULL;              // <- This is my second problem.
    }

private:

    int* m_p2d[3];                     // <- And I don't know how to specify this either.

};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you declare the argument

```
int* _2dIn[3]
```

you actually declare an array of pointers, instead of a pointer to an array.

You have to use parantheses to get the right meaning:

```
int (*_2dIn)[3]
```

Comment: It works.  Thanks,Both answers are correct.  This one is directly to the point.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that the member is an array of pointers to `int`, which does not have the same layout as a 2D array (there are no pointers in a 2D array).

You can make the argument to the constructor `int _2dIn[][3]`, but this is really just a `int (*_2dIn)[3]` in disguise - that is, a pointer to an array. When you pass the 2D array in, it automatically undergoes *array-to-pointer* conversion, and you get a pointer to the first element. If you then make the member the same type, you won't need to cast anything at all.

However, dealing with arrays like this is likely to lead you to trouble. If the `C` object outlives the array that was passed to it, it will be holding a pointer to an invalid object. Instead, you should look at using standard container types, like `std::array` or `std::vector`.